# Have a Tor Relay working from a VPN providers address. What if I change cities?

Tags: vpn, ip-address

I do that from time to time when the IP address I'm using gets blocked by the Barracuda blacklist (or others) and the wife starts complaining about lost Kroger access :(

When I change IPs, will Tor even care? Or will this become a big production?

Had believed that TOR was only about certificate signatures - not IP addresses. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your IP, your relay will be "down" until the next consensus is published with an updated IP address.

It won't be able to be used until the next consensus is published at the top of the hour and clients have downloaded the updated information. e.g. if you change IP at 00:05 your relay won't be usable again till some time after 01:00.